# Unable to maximize window of an external process

Tags: c#, .net

I have so far been unsuccessful in maximizing an external window.
I can get the handle and bring it to the foreground.
But it won't maximize.

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
IntPtr handle;

foreach (Process process in processlist)
{
    if (process.ProcessName == "wfica32")
    {
        handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(handle);
        ShowWindowAsync(handle, 3); // or SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED//  = 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **'ProcessID'** instead of process.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    private const int SwShowmaximized = 3;
    private void Run()
    {
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process process in processlist.Where(process => process.ProcessName == "wfica32"))
        {
            ShowWindow(Process.GetProcessById(process.Id).MainWindowHandle, SwShowmaximized);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try unsafe method.

```
// Pinvoke declaration for ShowWindow
private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

// Sample usage
ShowWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Didn't work. Window shows up but is not active. Perhaps I can activate it somehow?

Comment: Add a call to [SetForegroundWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/SetForegroundWindow.html) after the ShowWindow.

Comment: None of that code is `unsafe`. I know this because the [`unsafe` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx) is not anywhere in the code.